# Socrata SODA example with java undefined method

Tags: java, socrata

I am trying to execute the example found on the [socrata-soda Api](https://github.com/socrata/soda-java) which is

```
import com.socrata.api.HttpLowLevel;
import com.socrata.api.Soda2Consumer;
import com.socrata.model.soql.SoqlQuery;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
.....
Soda2Consumer consumer = Soda2Consumer.newConsumer("https://sandbox.demo.socrata.com",
                "testuser@gmail.com",
                "OpenData",
                "D8Atrg62F2j017ZTdkMpuZ9vY");

ClientResponse response = consumer.getHttpLowLevel().query("nominationsCopy",
                HttpLowLevel.JSON_TYPE,
                SoqlQuery.SELECT_ALL);
```

This however is giving me this error

```
The method query(String, MediaType, SoqlQuery) is undefined for the type  HttpLowLevel
```

I had a look at the java doc, but couldn’t find anything to help me. There isnt even a `query` method on [HttpLowLevel](http://socrata.github.io/soda-java/apidocs/com/socrata/api/HttpLowLevel.html) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `query` method on the `Soda2Consumer` class instead. You also don't need to authenticate unless you're accessing a private dataset or updating a dataset. Here's what the example should reflect:

```
    Soda2Consumer consumer = Soda2Consumer.newConsumer("https://sandbox.demo.socrata.com");

    ClientResponse response = consumer.query("nominationsCopy",
            HttpLowLevel.JSON_TYPE,
            SoqlQuery.SELECT_ALL);
    String payload = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(payload);
```

I'll update the example in GitHub too.